# Guava iterators, and iterating over a list within a list object

Tags: java, iterator, guava

I have the following example code which consists of 3-nested for-loops.

```
for(Continent continent : continentList) 
{
    for(Country country : continent.getCountries())
    {
        for(City city : country.getCities())
        {
            //Do stuff with city objects
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to mimic this nested for-loop using Guava and iterators? I've been trying to find a suitable example without much luck, and I was wondering if someone could help me out? A coworker of mine mentioned using filters.

EDIT: Fixed tiny bug in example code

Comment: You could nest your mappings.  IMHO it's likely to be simpler as nested loops, for the outer loops at least.

Comment: In line 3, shouldn't that be "continent.getCountries()" ?

Comment: You could use guavas "transform" and "concat" to create a single list of <Continent, Country, City> triples and then iterate over that, but with Java 7 at least, the code will be rather ugly. I'd stay with the nested loops.

Answer (score 12):

As Peter Lawrey commented, this is almost certainly going to be simpler as nested loops. More over, the [Guava documentation](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) gives this warning:

> Imperative code should be your default, your first choice as of Java
>   7. You should not use functional idioms unless you are absolutely sure of one of the following:
>
> - Use of functional idioms will result in net savings of lines of code
>     for your entire project. Moving the definition
>     of a function to another file, or a constant, does not help.
> - For efficiency, you need a lazily computed view of the transformed
>     collection and cannot settle for an explicitly computed collection.
>     Additionally, you have read and reread Effective Java, item 55, and
>     besides following those instructions, you have actually done
>     benchmarking to prove that this version is faster, and can cite
>     numbers to prove it.
>
> Please be sure, when using Guava's functional
>   utilities, that the traditional imperative way of doing things isn't
>   more readable. Try writing it out. Was that so bad? Was that more
>   readable than the preposterously awkward functional approach you were
>   about to try?

However, if you're insistent on ignoring advice, you could use something like this monstrosity (note I haven't actually tried to compile or run this):

```
FluentIterable.from(continentList)
    .transform(new Function<Continent, Void>() {
        public Void apply(Continent continent) {
            return FluentIterable.from(continent.getCountries())
                .transform(new Function<Country, Void>() {
                    public Void apply(Country country) {
                        return FluentIterable.from(country.getCities())
                            .transform(new Function<City, Void>() {
                                public Void apply(City city) {
                                    // do stuff with city object
                                    return null;
                                }
                            });
                    }
                });
        }
    });
```

Now ask yourself: Which would you want to maintain? Which is going to be the most efficient?

There are valid use-cases for Guava's functional idiom. Replacing Java for loops, even nested for loops, is not one of them.

Comment: Using [`FluentIterable.transformAndConcat()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html), you can chain the transformations instead of nesting them, though.

Comment: @FrankPavageau: True. But even if that's going to be a bit cleaner, it's still going to be uglier and less readable than the nested loops.

Answer (score 8):

You can define static functions for:
• getCountries() in Continent, Continents or Functions
• getCities() in Country, Countries or Functions

Now you can do something like...

```
FluentIterable.from(continentList)
    .transformAndConcat(Continent.getCountriesFunction())
    .transformAndConcat(Country.getCitiesFunction())
    . //filter //tranform //find //toList() //etc.
```

If:
• You use Guava like this (more) often.
• And have certain rules/thoughts over where you define your Functions and Predicates.
• And have varying (complex) things to filter or search for.
Then it can be a great boon and can make many situations quite a bit easier. I know I'm glad I did.
If you use it sparsely, then I'll have to agree with @Louis Wasserman. Then it's not worth the hassle. Also, defining Functions and Predicates as an anonymous inner class like the other examples... is really ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Another monstrosity, using AbstractIterator:

```
    class CityIterable implements Iterable<City> {
        List<Continent> continents;

        CityIterable(List<Continent> continents) {
            this.continents = continents;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<City> iterator() {
            return new AbstractIterator<City>() {
                Iterator<Continent> continentIterator = continents.iterator();
                Iterator<Country> countryIterator;
                Iterator<City> cityIterator;

                @Override
                protected City computeNext() {
                    if (cityIterator != null && cityIterator.hasNext()) {
                        return cityIterator.next();
                    }
                    if (countryIterator != null && countryIterator.hasNext()) {
                        cityIterator = countryIterator.next().getCities().iterator();
                        return computeNext();
                    }
                    if (continentIterator.hasNext()) {
                        countryIterator = continentIterator.next().getCountries().iterator();
                        return computeNext();
                    }
                    return endOfData();
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Then calling it:

```
    for (City city: new CityIterable(continentList)) {
        System.out.println(city.name);
    }
```

Given how this monstruosity, follow ig0774's advice and *keep the nested loops*.

P.S. No need for filters.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't an easy way. Also, it would be more verbose than the for-each loop in your question.

See http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=218#c5 and the caveats in http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others in that the nested loops are the most efficient way to go. However: I'd extract each loop level to a separate method to both maintain readability and make sure that each method does exactly one thing:

```
public void doStuffWithWorld(World world){
    for (Continent continent : world.getContinents()) {
        doStuffWithContinent(continent);
    }
}

private void doStuffWithContinent(Continent continent) {
    for (Country country : continent.getCountries()) {
        doStuffWithCountry(country);
    }
}

private void doStuffWithCountry(Country country) {
    for(City city : country.getCities()){
        doStuffWithCity(city);
    }
}

private void doStuffWithCity(City city) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

And if you need to carry some state through the different levels, you have several options: put them in member fields of the containing class, pass a second parameter to all the methods which can either be a map or a custom object.

Comment: I really like your suggestion; it will also also me to unit test each individual looper function if need be. Thanks :)